# Confusion over webhook utilization, Stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments, mern

I have a new issue arising regarding my implementation of Stripe webhooks. My platform is fully integrated, however, my implementation has a few issues. So currently I am working with a MERN Stack that fulfills authentication through use of Refresh Tokens and Access Tokens. Access tokens have roughly a 5-minute expiry. However, I had a few questions regarding how I should manage user updates. At the moment, my User.subscription sub-schema is the following.

```
        subscription: {
            status: { type: String, required: false },
            customer_id : { type: String, required: true },
            subscription_id: { type: String, required: false },
            latest_invoice_id: { type: String, required: false },
            payment_intent_id : { type: String, required: false },
            billing_date: { type: String, required: false },
            payment_intent_status : { type: String, required: false },
            card_last4 : { type: Number, required: false },
            card_type : { type: String, required: false },
            cancel_at_end: { type: Boolean, required: false }
        }
```

Basically, each access token will be signed with their subscription.status to verify that the subscription is active. Then, to figure out which control-flow to handle on the frontend, I will look at both the subscription.status and subscription.payment_intent_status. Is this a worth-while implementation? I will be looking for events regarding payment_intents and subscriptions through webhooks. However, in my live checkout the plan is to update the user with each payment attempt, so a new access-token can be signed for the user. But in this case, a webhook will be posted and re-attempt and update on the webhook route. Is there a better way to tackle this?

Thanks
Nich

Comment: You shouldn't need to check both the subscription.status and the subscription.payment_intent_status. The subscription.status alone should tell you whether the subscription is active or not. Can you say more about why you'd need to check that?

Comment: Yeah, definitely @cjav_dev. So the main point with the payment intent status is so I can handle Action Required control flows such as 3D secure, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, yeah you should only need that if there is a payment failure. In which case the subscription status would be "incomplete"

Comment: Yep! So my solution to this was only really saving things relevant to the subscription object. In the case of an incomplete subscription, I will make a call to the stripe api for the client to handle the payment_intent etc. Does that sound alright?